# Cannot open Edge with selenium on Ubuntu

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, microsoft-edge

I am trying to open Edge from selenium with python selenium-4.11.2.

I have downloaded the msedgedriver (version 115.0.1901.203; same as installed Edge) and run the following code snippet:

```
from selenium import webdriver

edgedriver = join(HOME, "webdrivers", "msedgedriver")  # path to driver
service = webdriver.EdgeService(executable_path=edgedriver)
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=service)

driver.get("https://google.com")  # Try google.com
```

So far so good. With the above snippet adjusted for Chrome, everything works as expected. However, with the presented snippet for Edge, selenium still runs Chrome. I am new to selenium, but could not find anyone else having this issue.

Comment: Do you have Microsoft Edge installed on your Ubuntu system? Also, share any error you are getting while executing.

Comment: Yes, Microsoft Edge is installed, and I can use it without any troubles. I won't receive any error, but the program is stuck at `driver.get(...)`

Comment: Can you try using the below approaches to initialize driver. For second option you need to install and use webdriver manager - pip install webdriver_manager 
1. driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=edgedriver)
 2. driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=EdgeDriverManager().install())

Comment: Since `selenium-4.10.0`, WebDrivers do not have an `executable_path` argument anymore. I don't know what EdgeDriverManager is, but Selenium should run with the correct webdriver setup. I will try out if Firefox works

Comment: You can get an understanding of webdriver manager from here this will help you to initialize any browser driver without downloading any binaries - https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for whatever reason, edge was assigned the default binary location `/usr/bin/google-chrome`.

This can be fixed by explicitly updating the binary path as

```
options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/microsoft-edge"
```